# How to use JHipster translation i18 for custom component

Tags: jhipster

Using JHipster 4.4.1 i want to use the translation feature (jhiTranslate="") for a custom component. In the component foo ts file:

```
constructor(
    private jhiLanguageService: JhiLanguageService
) {
    this.jhiLanguageService.setLocations(['foo']);
}
```

In the html file:

```
<h3 jhiTranslate="foo.title">title</h3>
```

And in webapp\i18n\en\foo.json

```
{
    "foo": {
        "title":"hello"
    }
}
```

Resulting in:
**translation-not-found[foo.title]**

How is it done right?

Comment: did you reload webpack process? language changes are not always working with HMR

Comment: @DavidSteiman this worked for me thanks. Can you add it as an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

To make language changes work you will need to reload the webpack process.

It sometimes works without reloading, but not with version 4.4.